# FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User inherits from BaseUser, but this class didn't exists

Tags: symfony, bundle, propel

I'm going to use `Fos\UserBundle\Propel\User` as extension for my own user class.

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Propel;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Propel\om\BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
    ...
}
```

My problem is, that the BaseUser class didn't exists. There is no `om` directory inside the `Fos\UserBundle\Propel` directory.

```
composer.json:
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
"willdurand/propel-typehintable-behavior": "~1.0",
```

How can I generate this file?!

Answer (score 0):

Does it not work if you just extend using

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem was, that the needed models weren't created when I run propel:model:build. I dunno where this comes from, but there is a ["workaround"](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/issues/215)

Comment: Console commands seem to do their own thing sometimes. Glad you got it sorted.